# Accessing thread state from main process

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently writing a Python program with a main process distributing work to a number of worker threads via separate worker queues per thread.

I am now having the problem that the main process needs to know what kind of work a worker thread is doing at a particular moment, since the job allocation depends on this (no other worker thread may be allocated a job of type X  if a job of type X is currently being processed by some other worker thread). Because of that, the individual worker threads need to maintain some sort of state that can be accessed by the main process at any time.

What is a thread safe way to do this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to this site, Simon! Programming questions are more suitable for StackOverflow than here.

Comment: Are you familiar with mutexes?  Mutex protected data is the de-facto standard way to solve these sorts of problems.  Sometimes you'll need to play games with condition variables too, but from what you've described, a simple mutex is all you need.

Comment: Hm, I thought mutexes are always owned by a particular thread and cannot be set/unset by another thread due to this ownership constraint. I am thinking about using a dictionary of Semaphores with a key/value pair for each job type. What do you think of this?

Comment: The worker locks the thread when it updates its job in a variable, updates it, then unlocks it.  Later, the main thread can lock it, read the current state of the job from that variable, then unlock it.  The mutex isn't the job state, it's a structure to protect the job state.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you! The Python equivalent of a mutex would be a `threading.Lock()`?

Comment: Also I would need one mutex/Lock per thread then?

Comment: @SimonFromme mutexs protect resources, it is not one per thread but one per resource. Be sure to release each mutex before locking another, or you will have many problems to solve...

Comment: @Frank Hileman: Yes sure, but if the resource is an object attribute (like in this case) it would be one per thread?

Comment: @SimonFromme in this particular case, you should not use a mutex, but an immutable bit of data somewhere. That is, that data (what worker does what type of work) should be assigned at the same time you assign a job, and the worker does not modify it, so it is a resource owned only by the "assigner", not the worker.

Answer (score 1):

> no other worker thread may be allocated a job of type X if a job of type X is currently being processed by some other worker thread

Then the resource that needs to be protected here is type X.

Before any worker thread does work on anything of type X it must test if some X thing is being worked on.  If it's not then it must set type X as being worked on and it must do this atomically.  That is, the worker thread must not allow a test from some other thread to sneak between it's own test and set.  This is the [test and set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) problem.

Rather than [poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) the worker threads consider letting them tell you their state when it changes ([event driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing))). Following the [observer pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Observer.html) is a good way to build your own event system. Polling doesn't always [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) well.

Another way to solve this problem is to have one of your queues be just for things of type X.  When a worker finishes with an X thing it tells the type X queue it's done.  Now the X queue can stop pretending to be empty. So long as nothing else offers up an X for processing we'll have prevented concurrent processing of X type things.